# Use patient ID to retrieve specific record from Access DB

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have an Access database containing fictional patients, along with various data (such as address, consultation notes and date), and so forth.

I have set it up so that each time a record is committed to the database, it is given a unique ID number, i.e 1001, 1002, and so on.

**(For those who are unsure as to what my question is, this is it) -->** What I want to do is use that ID number, and load the data from a record into controls on the screen. I should mention that this is a Windows Forms Application, and that I've already setup a form to handle (i.e. pass the entered ID number as a parameter) to the appropriate method.

The code comes in three sets.

The first is the code that the button executes when it is clicked, (so it will pass the  string, cast as an integer into the appropriate method).

The second set is the method which the ID is passed to -- it includes the SQL query that selects the information I need.

The final set is the "reader", which displays the information of the record in the associated TextBoxes by using an accessor method from the appropriate class.

The first set:

```
private void btnLoadPatientRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxPatientID.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter a Patient ID Number to proceed.", "ATTENTION!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else
        {
            patientID = Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxPatientID.Text);
            dmAccessor.loadPatientRecord(patientID);
        }
```

The second set:

```
public void loadPatientRecord(int patientID)
      {

          string connString = "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source= C:\\temp\\IntelliMed.accdb";
          string queryString = "SELECT * FROM PatientRecord WHERE ID = @patientID ";
```

The third set : (The 2nd and 3rd are actually two sets of code, one after the other, but I'm splitting them up for readability purposes).

I should also mention that I've spent about 12 hours straight on this problem, with no result.

```
try
          {
              using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
              {
                OleDbCommand cmnd = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
                connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = cmnd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string patReaderFirstName = reader.GetString(3);
                    string patReaderLastName = reader.GetString(5);
                    string patReaderGender = reader.GetString(6);
                    string patReaderDateOfBirth = reader.GetString(7);
                    string patReaderResidentialAddress = reader.GetString(8);
                    string patReaderPostalAddress = reader.GetString(9);
                    string patReaderNHINumber = reader.GetString(10);
                    string patReaderConsultDate = reader.GetString(11);
                    string patReaderConsultNotes = reader.GetString(12);

                    //Data processing code below this line.
                    PatientRecord patientRecordClassOverseer = new PatientRecord();
                    patientRecordClassOverseer.setPatientFirstName(patReaderFirstName);
                    patientRecordClassOverseer.setPatientLastName(patReaderLastName);
                    patientRecordClassOverseer.setPatientGender(patReaderGender);
                    patientRecordClassOverseer.setDateOfBirth(patReaderDateOfBirth);
                    patientRecordClassOverseer.setPatientResidentialAddress(patReaderResidentialAddress);
                    patientRecordClassOverseer.setPostalAddress(patReaderPostalAddress);
                    patientRecordClassOverseer.setPatientNHINumber(patReaderNHINumber);
                    patientRecordClassOverseer.setPatientConsultationDate(patReaderConsultDate);
                    patientRecordClassOverseer.setPatientConsultationNotes(patReaderConsultNotes);
                }
                reader.Close();

                }
              ctnIntelliMed.Close();

          }

          catch (Exception exf)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Sorry, an error has occurred while attempting to load the selected record from the database. Please try this again.");
          }
      }
```

Help is gratefully received, and many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: Have you add @patientID as a parameter to this query? I don't see it

Comment: Smth like cmnd.AddParameter("@patientID", patientID)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I'm asking for some help to load a patient's record by using their unique record ID number, but I need to know how to send that information to the DB correctly so I can then have the reader display the correct information.

Comment: @ValentynVynograskiy I'm not sure how I can add it, given the way I've written the query.

Comment: So you're asking how to pass the parameter value alongside the SQL?

Comment: @ValentynVynograskiy Would it go just under "cmnd" 's object instantiation?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, that's exactly it! :) Then, hopefully, a record will load when its number is used.

Comment: For future reference, it really helps if you actually ask a question when posting a question. Best of luck with your program.

Comment: @Valentyn Vynogradskiy I have added it just under cmnd = new OleDBCommand(...) -> etcetera. Is that correct?

Comment: @Paul - I think it should do the thing

Comment: @ValentynVynogradskiy I have just done that, and when I pressed "Load Record", it is causing the application to hang.

Comment: @Paul - try update in my answer

Comment: @ValentynVynogradskiy I have done so, but strangely, no data appears.

Comment: @Paul - have u debug - what are you sending and what youre executing on the db. Point breake before ExecuteReader - inspect cmnd try find what query I generates - and try it in your data base

Comment: @ValentynVynogradskiy I will let you know. I have a hunch about something. If it this hunch is correct, then maybe things will work.

Comment: @ValentynVynogradskiy I am sending an integer, which is the patientID. The query generated was: "SELECT * FROM PatientRecord WHERE patientID = @patientID"

Comment: The patientID is classed as a "Number" in the DB, and is of type "Long Integer"

Answer (score 0):

I think you've miss parameter adding

```
cmnd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@patientID", patientID);
```

Try this

Please try this

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
              {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmnd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmnd.CommandText = queryString;
                cmnd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@patientID", patientID);
                OleDbDataReader reader = cmnd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {....
```

Answer (score 0):

what is your datatype of `patientID` variable??

use `where` clause  as if it is `varchar`

```
WHERE ID = '"& patientID &"'  OR  '"+ patientID +"'
```

and  if it is integer then u can try...

```
where ID="& paitentID &"  OR  "+ patientID +"
```

when we write the variable in where clause then only use this charecter & or + this is  a syntex   that i used many times. you try + first .and if we write any value then it is not needed.

Comment: It is an integer. (See the second set of code). I will give your solution a go, though the "&" in your answer has me confused, I do not know why it is there?